# Kill ssh background process after disconnect / timeout?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I frequently use ssh tunnels to access VNC sessions on remote machines, but this is on my laptop so the connections break when I put it to sleep for the night.  If I then try to re-open the connection in the morning, I have to manually kill the ssh session, otherwise I get this error:

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 1202
Could not request local forwarding.
```

The SSH command I'm using is this:

```
ssh -N -C -f -L 1202:localhost:5900 name@server
```

What's the best way to have the ssh tunnel die when it disconnects?  Or reset?

Answer (score 0):

For automatic restarting of an ssh session, try using [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/)